Trying to force Tomcat to use HTTPS with a wildcard certificate
I was handed a problem where we had a dev server that has never used HTTPS before since there has never been any real data on it. However we now need this to be HTTPS, out prod server is but the person who set it up left long ago. This is a Windows 2012 server as well so we are trying to get this moved to HTTPS so then we can migrate to a new 2019 server.
We have a wildcard certificate that we are attempting to use everywhere we can and replace the numerous old certs. Unlucky for me our current prod server to this dev server uses one of the oddball certs. The issue I keep running into is when I attempt to  use a created keystore I continuously receive a  Invalid character found in method name ... HTTP method names must be tokens error in the catalina log and obviously the web page doesn't load.
My connector in my config I believe is setup properly it is as follows...
<Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="D:\XXXXXX\tomcat.p12" 
               keystorePass="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
               >
    </Connector>

I have tried everything, I have been attempting to force this to use HTTPS but I am at a loss at this point, any help is appreciated.
I have recreated the keystore multiple times. I have verified firewall rules are in for port 8180. I have tried basically copying the config from prod to dev and just changing the keystore file part of config but this hasn't worked either.

This is not a programming or development issue and thus offtopic, but: the only way I can see you would get an error like that is with pretty old Tomcat and clients that wrongly try to connect to https://whatever.example:8180 -- which you could determine by looking at or showing the entire error message not just a few words here and there. If the clients are doing that, fix them. (BTW putting SSL/TLS config on the Connector no longer works if you upgrade all the way to tomcat 10, but leave that aside for now.)
